# T4MVC Optional Parameter Inferred From Current Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, t4mvc

I have read the other post about this at [T4MVC OptionalParameter values implied from current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566207/t4mvc-optionalparameter-values-implied-from-current-context) and I am using the latest T4MVC (2.11.1) which is suppose to have the fix in. I even checked checked to make sure that it's there -- and it is.

I am still getting the optional parameters filled in based on the current context.

For example: Let's say I have a list that is by default ordered by a person's last name. I have the option to order by first name instead with the URL

```
http://localhost/list/stuff?orderby=firstname
```

When I am in that page, I want to go back to order by first name with the code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("order by last name", MVC.List.Stuff(null))
```

the link I wanted was simply

```
http://localhost/list/stuff
```

without any parameters to keep the URL simple and short - invoking default behaviors within the action. But instead the **orderby** is kept and the url is still

```
http://localhost/list/stuff?orderby=firstname
```

Any help would be great. I know that in the most general cases, this does remove the query parameter - maybe I do have a specific case where it was not removed. I find that it only happens when I have the URL inside a page that I included with RenderPartial.

My actual code is

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Recently Updated",  MVC.Network.Ticket.List(Model.UI.AccountId, "LastModifiedDate", null, null, null, null, null))</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Recently Created",  MVC.Network.Ticket.List(Model.UI.AccountId, "CreatedDate", null, null, null, null, null))</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Most Severe",       MVC.Network.Ticket.List(Model.UI.AccountId, "MostSevere", null, null, null, null, null))</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Previously Closed", MVC.Network.Ticket.List(Model.UI.AccountId, "LastModifiedDate", null, "Closed", null, null, null))</li>
```

the problem happens when someone clicks Previously Closed and and go to **?status=closed**. When they click Recently Updated, which I want the status parameter gone (passed a null). But ?status=closed stays in the generated url.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 10/16/12**

the code:

```
@html.action("Profile", MVC.Profile.Index())
```

generated the url:

```
http://localhost:55059/network/ticket/14441327-128b-e111-af72-0050569e0924?Controller=profile&Action=index
```

This only happens on a specific page. This is pretty dangerous actually...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can piece together from online sources, this behavior is not attributable to T4MVC but to the MVC framework itself.  Something about which helper functions T4MVC uses.  In my project, I just switched over to the vanilla MVC syntax.  Monkeying with the anonymous object being passed in as `routeValues` will give you explicit control over the query string parameters.  Doing something like the following will always work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Recently Updated", "Ticket", "Network", new { Id = Model.UI.AccountId, orderby = "LastModifiedDate" }, null))
```

...and generate HTML like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost:55059/Network/Ticket/14441327-128b-e111-af72-0050569e0924?orderby=LastModifiedDate">Recently Updated</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone still face this issue, here is what I found solution

http://yaweriqbal.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/actionlink-passing-parameter-as-querystring/