# Can I force T4MVC not to take a parameter from the URL of the current view, when generating new anchors within the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, t4mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 application, where I use T4MVC for conveniently generating anchor-elements within my views. Something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application 1", MVC.Application.Overview(1))
```

I have two routes in my RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
    name: "DefaultWithId",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{subaction}",
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" },
    defaults: new { subaction = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRouteLowercase(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

I have an Application controller, where some actions need an Id to a certain application, while other actions doesn't need an Id, since they aren't application specific (like a page that display all applications).

The routes works well for the most part, generating links like this:

```
/application/index        <-- Overview of all applications
/application/1/overview   <-- Overview of specific application
```

The problem arise when I am on `/application/1/overview` and try to create an anchor element back to the index-action. The generated link then end up `/application/1/index`, which is not a desired behavior.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I believe is going on here is that T4MVC recognizes that there is an application id available in the route of the current page and uses that id, so that it can make use of the `DefaultWithId` route, instead of `Default`, to generate a URL to the index-action.

I could of course force a proper anchor doing something like this:

```
@Html.RouteLink(
     "All applications", 
     "Default", 
      new { controller = "Application", action = "Index"})
```

But that feels like I'm curing the symptom rather than the actual problem. I also loose the beauty of compile-time check of all anchors, so I'd rather do something else.

**Is there a way to force T4MVC to ignore the parameters of the current page, when generating anchors in the view? Or can I modify my routes somehow to avoid this behavior?**

Answer (score 1):

*"T4MVC recognizes that there is an application id available in the route of the current page and uses that id, so that it can make use of the DefaultWithId route, instead of Default, to generate a URL to the index-action"*

T4MVC has no such smarts, but instead these are built into the MVC routing systems. But a number of T4MVC users have run into that before. Various references:

- [T4MVC OptionalParameter values implied from current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566207/t4mvc-optionalparameter-values-implied-from-current-context)
- https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/discussions/399824

Comment: Thanks for the references! I still haven't been able to solve the problem, but this gives me a bit more to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the action method to have id parameter as null. Like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult xyz(int? id)
{
  return View();
}
```

Now pass the id whenever you need to pass otherwise leave it. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem though isn't how to create an action that can take an optional ID. The problem is that I'd like to force T4MVC to generate URL's without an ID for any action that doesn't take an Id.